# How to fix show Text in Spinner on Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

In my application I want use `Spinner` and for this I use [custom library](https://github.com/ganfra/MaterialSpinner).
**But show me half of Text!!!**
For this I write below codes in XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/SerialReview_GenreLay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/SerialReview_SortByLay"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SerialReview_GenreTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size15"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="@string/reviewType"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font16" />

                <fr.ganfra.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/SerialReview_ReviewType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size50"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SerialReview_GenreTitle"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                    app:ms_alignLabels="true"
                    app:ms_arrowColor="@color/darkBlueGrey"
                    app:ms_arrowSize="@dimen/padding10"
                    app:ms_enableFloatingLabel="false"
                    app:ms_multiline="false"
                    app:ms_thickness="0dp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size0.2"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/SerialReview_ReviewType"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mines10"
                    android:background="@color/darkBlueGrey" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

But when run application in device show me text such as below image :
[image]

How can I fix this issue? Please help me

Comment: Have you tried using `wrap_content` instead of `@dimen/size50` for the layout_height of your material spinner?

Comment: @MatPag, thanks my bro. your answer solve my problem <3

Comment: Nice to hear ;)